# How to rewrite this function to be tail-recursive？

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I'm reading the book *The Little Schemer*, I implement the functions in Clojure, How to rewrite this function as a tail-recursive function in Clojure?

```clj
(defn rember*
    [a lat]
    (cond
        (empty? lat) []
        (clojure.inspector/atom? (first lat))
            (if (= a (first lat))
                (rember* a (rest lat))
                (cons (first lat)
                      (rember* a (rest lat))))
        :else
            (cons (rember* a (first lat))
                  (rember* a (rest lat)))))
```

Comment: Have you _tried_ using `recur`? If you've got code representing an attempt that doesn't compile, that's a good starting place (we can explain _why_ it doesn't compile)

Comment: I tried to use `recur`, but I failed. I can't think of how to use `recur` to rewrite this function.

Comment: In general, any case where `recur` isn't allowed is a case where Scheme wouldn't be successful at applying TCO either. :)

Comment: ...by my current read, only one of your `rember*` calls -- the one where `(= a (first lat))` is true --  is in tail position. In the others you're doing something else with the result after it's returned (typically `cons`ing it), so it's not in tail position.

Comment: I don't understand how to write this sentence when `recur` is used.
`(cons (rember* a (first lat)) (rember* a (rest lat)))`

Comment: _nod_, none of the recursions in that piece are in tail position, so you can't. You'd need to refactor the function, presumably to have an entirely different calling convention. I don't know that this function's purpose is, so I'm not in a position to suggest what a refactor should look like.

Comment: (while the real reason for `recur`'s restrictions come down to the JVM's historical calling conventions, there's a happy side effect that they stop people from writing code that they _think_ is TCO-eligible but actually isn't, which is not exactly uncommon in Scheme).

Comment: Delete all specified values in a nested list.
`(rember* sauce ((tomato sauce)) ((bean) sauce) (and
((flying)) sauce)))`
=> `(((tomato)) ((bean)) (and ((flying)))`

Comment: Do you have any good ideas

Comment: So, where I'd start is by trying to reframe it as "how would I implement this without a stack, having just a regular loop?"; once you have an algorithm that would work with a loop, it's easy to convert that to an algorithm using TCO.

Comment: You can definitely do _some_ TCO here, but getting it to 100% TCO honestly seems pretty tricky, at least at first glance. Unless given a firm contrary requirement, I'd probably resign myself to having as many stack frames as there are nesting levels.

Comment: Yes, this is a thorny problem for me, and I will continue to try to solve it. Thank you very much for your discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a translation of your code to a version that uses a loop and two lists instead of recursion in order to maintain program state:

```
(defn rember* [a lat]
  (loop [[[op-type a lat] & rest-ops] (list [:rember a lat])
         data '()]
    (case op-type
      nil (first data)
      :value (recur rest-ops (cons a data))
      :rember (cond
                (empty? lat) (recur rest-ops (cons '() data))
                
                (clojure.inspector/atom? (first lat))
                (if (= a (first lat))
                  (recur (cons [:rember a (rest lat)] rest-ops) data)
                  (recur (into rest-ops [[:cons]
                                         [:rember a (rest lat)]
                                         [:value (first lat)]])
                         data))
                :else (recur (into rest-ops [[:cons]
                                             [:rember a (rest lat)]
                                             [:rember a (first lat)]])
                             data))
      :cons (let [[a b & data] data]
              (recur rest-ops (cons (cons b a) data))))))
```

Comment: `clojure.inspector/atom?` has this source `(source clojure.inspector/atom?)
-> (defn atom? [x] (not (coll? x)))`, so OP used it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. My negligence. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, `loop`-`recur` is the more clojuresk answer!

But for a tail-recursive version, you could also do:

```
(def atom? (complement coll?))

(defn rember* 
  ([a lat] (rember* a lat []))
  ([a lat acc]
   (cond (empty? lat) (seq acc) ;; or just `acc` when result should be vector
         (atom? (first lat)) (if (= a (first lat))
                               (rember* a (rest lat) acc)
                               (rember* a (rest lat) (conj acc (first lat))))
         :else (rember* a (rest lat) (conj acc (rember* a (first lat)))))))
```

With this, you can easily build `loop-recur` by replacing the recursive function call using `recur`. However note that the last call of `rember*` cannot be placed by `recur` - because you cannot nest `recur` calls.

```
(defn rember* [a lat]
  (loop [a a
         lat lat
         acc []]
    (cond (empty? lat) (seq acc)
          (atom? (first lat)) (if (= a (first lat))
                                (recur a (rest lat) acc)
                                (recur a (rest lat) (conj acc (first lat))))
          :else (recur a (rest lat) (conj acc (rember* a (first lat)))))))
```

Comment: I think you should remove that final `seq`. Compare `(rember* 1 [1 [1] 1])` with `seq` and without, `(= '(nil) [[]]) => false`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will cause stack overflow when nested enough.

Comment: Hm true ... the nested recursive call is problematic I think